# Custom startup scene breaks addons?

Tags: add-on, customization, scene, startup-file

I run Blender with my own custom startup scene. I've installed some new addons recently and a couple of them just didn't work with no error or indication of the problem. What I discovered is that opening Blender in the default startup scene with my same preferences fixes the problem.

What exactly would cause a modified startup scene to break addon functionality and how could this be properly prevented? There shouldn't be anything fundamentally different between it and the default.

Comment: I guess this is very highly speculative to answer since we have no information how much and what you have changed in your custom startup scene, and even if you would have revealed which new addons are affected by this, you cannot expect us to know how all these addons work.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I figured, but the only things that were changed were the layout and removing the default objects. Resetting preferences changed nothing, but resetting the startup scene did. Only thing I've read that could indicate is how much might change between versions, potentially requiring re-building your startup scene.

Comment: I'm not sure what versions have to do with it. Are those addons made for a different version of Blender? Or have you used an old startup file for a newer version of Blender or...?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The addons are verified for the latest version, so I assume it's because I was using an old startup file made on a previous version. Not sure why that's would cause problems though.

Comment: Well, the startup file stores a lot of things, not only the default cube, lamp and camera, but also the render engine settings, some editor settings etc. And some of the things are changed or maybe even vanished from one version to another so I can imagine that this causes problems. And in your question  you just said your own custom startup scene. Customizing alone usually is no problem - that's why you have the option to save it. But features change, so it's best to customize the file that matches the version it is used in.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The weird thing is that disabling and enabling the addon in the modified file does nothing, so the conflict must be more deeply embedded. Oh well.

Comment: It's not weird to me now that I know that you used an old startup file. I don't think it has to do with the addons per se, since the enabling/disabling of them is stored in the user preferences which you can change without having to save them in the startup file. I guess it's something in the basic features of Blender that is incompatible with the old file, so the foundation is the problem, not the addons built on top of that.